# Numpy array and column extracted from a matrix, different shape

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I'm trying to do an integration with numpy:

```
A = n.trapz(B,C)
```

but I have some issues with B and C shapes

B is a filled array inizialized with numpy zeros function

```
B=np.zeros((N,1))
```

C is a column extracted from a matrix, always inizialized with numpy:

```
C = D[:,0]
D = np.zeros((N,2))
```

the problem is that:

```
n.shape(B) # (N,1)
n.shape(C) # (N,)
```

how can I manage this?

Comment: What shape do you want?

Comment: @user2357112 I think `numpy.trapz()` wants an array like (N,)

Comment: Change B to `B = np.zeros((N,))`

Comment: Just so simple?
And if I want to reshape C? @BiRico

Comment: @BiRico the arrays are filled along the script I omitted here :D

Comment: You can reshape C by doing `C = C.reshape((N, 1))`, or `(-1, 1)` and numpy will figure out N for you, but know that `trapz(B, C)` in that case will return an (N,) array. Is that what you're after?

Comment: @BiRico No, I'm looking for a scalar as result of the integration. With both arrays with (N,) size it works as expected. As I can see, I have to specify axis. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
B = np.zeros(N)
np.trapz(B, C)
```

Also, you `np.trapz` accepts multi-dimensional arrays, so arrays of shape `(N, 1)` are ok; you just need to specify an axis to handle it properly.

```
B = np.zeros((N, 1))
C = D[:, 0]
np.trapz(B, C.reshape(N, 1), axis=1)
```